# Improper utf16 count for certain emoji's

Tags: swift, string

Certain emoji's that are actually a combination of emoji's result in the incorrect (or at least a count that doesn't match websites like Twitter).

Example problem is pretty straight forward

‍⚖ <- this emoji is a female judge (woman + scale)
The count of this emoji is 1
the utf16 count of this emoji in Swift is 4

```
let tweet = "‍⚖"
print(tweet.utf16.count)
```

However, pasting this emoji into Twitter (which is an emoji that Twitter doesn't seem to support you are given the two emoji's. Woman & Scale. Woman is 2 characters and scale is 2 characters when using utf16 count. However, Twitter seems to have a hidden albeit counted invisible character. You will notice this when you try to delete the characters. I'm wondering if there's some way to properly match Twitters count when on mobile. I've seen other websites which, while properly showing the single emoji, are still getting the proper count.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your question about Swift or about Twitter? 4 is the correct result, what would you like to get?

Comment: Note: Twitter considers it 5 characters, it inserts a space between the woman and the scale.

Comment: I don't know about Twitter, but the character consists of 3 Unicode scalars: U+0001F469, U+200D, U+2696 (Woman, Zero-width-joiner, Scales). The first one is represented by 2 UTF-16 code points (surrogate pair).

Comment: Made me think of that: https://twitter.com/objcio/status/943136869717610502 I don't know how Twitter counts characters, and/or what language they natively use, but it helps demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded Twitter pod and used weighted length for the solution here.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-text

For those who end up here with a similar problem, Twitter recommends you show progress rather than exact counts by using permillage.